# How to Remove Some Line from Text File Using PHP?

Tags: php, file

I have a text file contains this data :

> 947   11106620030     Ancho Khoren         MKK6203    Introduction
>   Busy 2,00
>  948 balblalbllablab
>  949 balblalbllablab
>  950
>   balblalbllablab
>   951   11106620031     Adagasa Goo       MKB6201    Economy Inside
>   3,00
>  952 balblalbllablab
>  953 balblalbllablab
>  954
>   balblalbllablab
>   962   11106620032     The Fumiou Moon     MKB6201    The Book of World
>   3,00

However, I need to remove all the lines containing 'balblabllablab' and just leave tge specific lines of data, as shown below:

> 947   11106620030     Ancho Khoren         MKK6203    Introduction
>   Busy      2,00
>  951   11106620031     Adagasa Goo       MKB6201
>   Economy Inside  3,00
>  962   11106620032     The Fumiou Moon MKB6201
>   The Book of World  3,00

I know how to open and write to a file aswell as closing the file, but  i don't know how to remove lines / content using php. How can I remove the unneeded lines from a file using php?

Comment: Open the file, read it line by line, open a new file and write the desired lines in it and dont write the ones you want to remove.

Comment: Yusufmm - your comment and code snippet aren't doing what @HankyPanky was describing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `file($path)` function to get the lines into an array, then loop through it.

```
$lines = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$remove = "balblalbllablab";
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
  if(stristr($line, $remove)) unset($lines[$key]);

$data = implode('\n', array_values($lines));

$file = fopen($path);
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: and how to remove the 948, 949, 950 number ?

Comment: That will be removed as part of the line also. When I use `unset($lines[$key])`, that removes the entire line from the array of lines.

Comment: must use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`for effective. and two params of `fopen` is needed `w` for write.
and so I don't know why need to `array_values` for get array or reindexing in here?! (I EDITED THE ANSWER)

Answer (score 1):

Contents in the file are not clear, what exactly you want to take from the text file?

Usually using regular expression you can fetch the required content, Only if it have some common pattern.

Can you please post the complete file content and explain what exactly you want to filter from it.

refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php