# Removing a line from the middle of a large file php

Tags: php, file

I am trying to remove a line from the middle of a large file. ( > 20MB). I know the position in the file of the start of the line to be removed.

Here is what I currently have.

```
/**
 * Removes a line at a position from the file
 * @param  [int] $position  The position at the start of the line to be removed
 */
public function removeLineAt($position)
{
    $fp = fopen($this->filepath, "rw+");
    fseek($fp, $position);

    $nextLinePosition = $this->getNextLine($position, $fp);
    $lengthRemoved = $position - $nextLinePosition;
    $fpTemp = fopen('php://temp', "rw+");

    // Copy the bottom half (starting at line below the line to be removed)
    stream_copy_to_stream($fp, $fpTemp, -1, $nextLinePosition);

    // Seek to the start of the line to be removed
    fseek($fp, $position);
    rewind($fpTemp);

    // Copy the bottom half over the line to be removed
    stream_copy_to_stream($fpTemp, $fp);        

    fclose($fpTemp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

However, while the code above does indeed remove the line from the file; since the temporary file is shorter than the original file. The tail end of the original file still exists and is doubled.

For Example:
Original file was

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e

The file after removing the line may look like

1. a
2. b
3. d
4. e
5. e

I have thought about somehow trimming the end of the main file by the $lengthRemoved amount however I can't think of an easy way to do that either.

Any suggestions?

- Note: The file has > 200,000 lines, sometimes > 300,000. I feel as if loading the entire file into an array (memory) would be pretty inefficient. Which is why I tried the above approach but ran into that one issue

---

For others who are looking for an answer here is the final function I came up with thanks to your help! Modify it to fit your needs.

```
/**
 * Removes a line at a position from the file
 * @param  [int] $position  The position at the start of the line to be removed
 */
public function removeLineAt($position)
{
    $fp = fopen($this->filepath, "rw+");
    fseek($fp, $position);

    $nextLinePosition = $this->getNextLine($position, $fp);
    $lengthRemoved = $position - $nextLinePosition;
    $fpTemp = fopen('php://temp', "rw+");

    // Copy the bottom half (starting at line below the line to be removed)
    stream_copy_to_stream($fp, $fpTemp, -1, $nextLinePosition);

    // Remove the difference
    $newFileSize = ($this->totalBytesInFile($fp) + $lengthRemoved);
    ftruncate($fp, $newFileSize);

    // Seek to the start of the line to be removed
    fseek($fp, $position);
    rewind($fpTemp);

    // Copy the bottom half over the line to be removed
    stream_copy_to_stream($fpTemp, $fp);        

    fclose($fpTemp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Remove Some Line from Text File Using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250773/how-to-remove-some-line-from-text-file-using-php)

Comment: The file has > 200,000 lines, and could contain > 400,000. I feel as if loading the entire file into an array (memory) would be pretty inefficient. Which is why I tried the above approach but ran into that one issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pretty close to a solution.

I would stick to your idea of removing the `$lengthRemoved` from the end of the file  and would suggest to use `ftruncate($handle, $size);` before the `fclose()`, where size is the size to truncate to (size = originalFilesize - lengthRemoved).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php

Comment: Thanks! That was the function I was looking for.

Comment: Does ftruncate load file in memory?

Comment: No, ftruncate() just truncates/shortens the handle to the requested size. You might want to look at fopen+fgets or file_get_contents for reading into memory.

Comment: The memory intensive part in this code is stream_copy_to_stream. But it could be replaced by feof,fwrite,fread.

Answer (score 2):

Since your file is very large you may want to use the `sed` command via `exec` if your php install will allow you to use that function.

```
exec("sed '3d' fileName.txt");
```

Where the `3` indicates the desired line number.