# Deleting specific text from text file using javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php

[image]

i have this jDialog box which reads/contains text file data in table format.
I want to delete entire row which will effect the text file after deleting.
I don't know how to do this please help.
My code:

```
<div id="dialog-5" style="border-style: solid; border-width:1px; border-color:silver;border-radius:4px;width:42%;background-color:lightyellow;">
                        <center>                                                                            <!-- read code here-->
                        <?php
                        echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="0">';
                        ?><tr><td><b>Delete</td><td><b>Description</td><td><b>Author</td><td><b>Date</td><td><b>Query</td></tr>
                        <?php
                        $file = fopen("QDAC.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
                        while (!feof($file)){   
                            $data = (fgets($file)); 
                            $arr  = (explode("~",$data));
                            // print_r($arr);
                            ?><tr onclick="SomeFunction('<?php echo $arr[0]?>')"><td><input type="button" value="Del" style="width:49px;background-color: tomato;border-radius:4px;" id="" name="" onclick="delTxt();"/></td><?php 
                            foreach($arr as $k)
                            {
                                ?><td><?php echo $k; ?></td><?php
                            }
                            ?></tr><?php 
                            //echo "<tr onclick='abc()'><td id='one'>" . str_replace('~','</td><td>',$data) . '</td></tr>';
                        }
                        echo '</table>';
                        fclose($file);
                        ?>
                        </center>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove Some Line from Text File Using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250773/how-to-remove-some-line-from-text-file-using-php)

Comment: let me try that thanku.